# setGravity not working

Tags: android, android-layout

Please see my code below. I am unable to make SetGravity work.

How come?

Layout Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a command"
        android:password="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/btnResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Results" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_weight="80"
        android:id="@+id/passTog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" android:checked="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
public class TextPlay extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.text);

        Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResults);
        final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.passTog);
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

        passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (passTog.isChecked()) {

                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

                } else {

                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

                }

            }
        });

        chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String check = input.getText().toString();

                Log.i(TAG, "Check Value is: " + check);

                if (check.contentEquals("left")) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "I am under left ");
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); //WHYW ILL YOU NOT WORK SETGRAVITY?????????????
                } else if (check.contentEquals("center")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                } else if (check.contentEquals("right")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }

                else if (check.contentEquals("blue")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tvResults does not align left or right after the user clicks the button even though I see the log message.

Comment: Have you tried using the `invalidate()` for the view? If the event is firing, maybe the View just doesn't know to redraw itself?

Comment: I tried doing results.invalidate(); and that did not do anything either.

Comment: @jini hi, had you finally solved this problem? I have encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested and it works.. You might be doing a few things wrong;

First of all, when you type "left" into the text field, are you making sure that you didn't type "Left" (most keyboards capitalize the first letter)

If you are sure about the above, do you see the log that says "I am under left " (Not the "Check is")? If not, then it's not getting there somehow..

If you are indeed seeing it, you might want to clean/build your project (in Eclipse Project-> Clean -it does cleaning and re-building)

If that doesn't work neither, you might want to change your target build (change it to API level 10 or so) You don't really need to worry about the target build if you are just using this as an exercise to learn.

Comment: I have tried everything you mentioned including the target build stuff and it still does not align the text to left. This concerns me as the same code is behaving differently om different machines.

Comment: I also do see "I am under left"

Comment: What are you running this on? Emulator (if so which OS) or device (which model and OS)?

Comment: I am running an Android Virtual Device: Target Android 4.0, API Level 14, WVGA800.

Answer (score 1):

I think we're not able to change UI this way. 
I usually do like this.

```
TableLayout table1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
txtresult.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
((TableLayout) table1).addView(txtresult);
```

It works with me.
So I suggest you to do a trick like delete that TextView "display" and generate a new one with new Gravity properties.

Hope it works!
Linh

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `layout_gravity="center"` and `layout_width="wrap_ontent"` maybe that will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

set `layout_width="wrap_content"` and set the layout gravity.

Comment: That did nothing. Just aligned the textview left as opposed to center as before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call invalidate after you change the layout attribute of your text view?

[Android Documentation - View.invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

Comment: I did results.invalidate(); and that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the conditions as below:

```
check.equalsIgnoreCase("left")
```

Hope this solves ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

View.invalidate() must be involved on UI thread. If you are doing the view re-configuration within a Listener callback which is your case, then you probably need call View.postInvalidate(), check out the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29):

> public void invalidate ()
>
> Since: API Level 1
> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of Doing :- tvResults.setGravity 
try setting gravity of linearlayout :- llResults.setGravity

Answer (score 0):

your code works good for me, i´ve tested on a real device with android 4.0.3 (Nexus S), the only thing that can be bothering you its capital letters as @Tolga E told.

you can try:

`check.equalsIgnoreCase("left")`

instead of:

`check.contentEquals("left")`

and debugging, put a breakpoint on the if´s to check that your code is actually trying to modify the gravity or its skipping that line.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone who's following thenewboston's tutorial stumbles upon this with the same problem, it's an issue with the display variable. Just change

```
 final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

to

```
 final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
```

up with the other variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I think setGravity method has been depreciated from API 4.0 . I don't see any alternative. Only way left you need to use API level 8.0. I am also getting nulpointer exceptions in log cat by using setGravity method

Answer (score 0):

Set your TextView's width as `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`then you can set it programmatically using `myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` .