# setGravity not working for RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[`This question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568007/setgravity-not-working) is similar to mine, but no constructive answer there.

I am trying to do a simple toggle of a header view in a list. I want the head of first section be in the left, and that of the second be in the right. The layout of this head view is a relativelayout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/location_list_pinned_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dip"
    android:background="#505050"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/zlocation_list_header_text"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And what I do in the java code is:

```
    RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) headerView.findViewById(R.id.location_list_pinned_header);
    if ( section%2 == 0 ) {
        ((TextView) headerView.findViewById(id))
                .setText(title);//set the section title, may be like "Feb" "Jan"
        header.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);//I am sure it is been set, I see the mGravity of RelativeLayout changed in debug mode
    }
    else {
        ((TextView) headerView.findViewById(id))
                .setText(title);
        header.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
```

As I am saying in the comments, I am sure the setGravity has set the value. But it's not changed. Should I perform some other action after I have set the layout param? Because if I have set the gravity to RIGHT in if clause, it is not shown in my screen. But if I scroll down and up again, it changed to right side, but still not as I expected, different position for each section. All section in this case went to right...

`headerView` is a View that holds the RelativeLayout:

```
mDisPlay.setPinnedHeaderView(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.zlocation_list_section_header, mDisPlay, false));
```

will set header view,`mDisPlay` is the list, like I said before. the layout used in this code is shown in the first excerpt of code. The following is the method `setPinnedHeaderView`

```
public void setPinnedHeaderView(View view) {
    mHeaderView = view;
    if (mHeaderView != null) {
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }
    System.out.println("setPinnedHeaderView");

    requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: What does your `header` to?

Comment: @GokhanArik Sorry, I didn't make it clear, see my updates. The header I think is the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Do you use that layout in every row of the `ListView`? Also how does the `headerView` look like?

Comment: @Luksprog It's a little bit complicated. Actually I use a extended ListView `PinnedHeaderListView` that have a pinned header fixed on top of the list, and when you get to the second section the header will change the text. This is something like in your contact, you group your friends alphabetically section from "A" to "Z". And I want to toggle the text position section by section to make it a little more attractive. As for the look of the list you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131020/change-the-layout-of-the-header-in-pinnedheaderlistview

Comment: @Luksprog I want to inflate a different layout in this question. But I failed, alternatively, I try do what I said in this question, still got a problem.

Comment: Without seeing the full code for the pinned `ListView` it would be hard to debug for someone else. From where do you call that piece of code for setting the gravity?

Comment: @Luksprog I solved this problem by change the layout_orientation to horizontal!!!

Comment: Aren't you maybe confusing `gravity` and `layout_gravity`? They are totally different properties. Anyway, `layout_gravity` is ignored for RelativeLayout's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `RelativeLayout` does not have an orientation property; remove this from your XML.

However, I don't see why you need a `RelativeLayout` parent for the header here; why not use `LinearLayout`? Give this vertical orientation, say, and set its gravity as you are.

If you can do away with the parent layout altogether so much the better. This one only has a single child.

Comment: Besides, `android:layout_gravity="top"` does not belong to [RelativeLayout's params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: That too, another example.

Comment: After changing that to LinearLayout and give it a **horizontal** orientation, problem is solved.